# What does “has ever been sent packing” mean?

Tags: meaning

I'm currently reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/trump-seriously-frighteningly-dangerously-nuts-050017280.html) and a paragraph says,

> **No president has ever been sent packing.** Nixon resigned because he saw it coming. Trump would sooner start a civil war.

What would this bold line mean?

I checked with Merriam Unabridged, it says,

Packing : noun

> 1 a :  the act or process of preparing goods for shipment or storage
>   
>   
>   specifically :  the wholesale processing of food for market
>
> b :  a method of inserting into a shipping container with appropriate protective covering, cushioning, or bracing
>
> c :  the act or process of transporting or being transported on the backs of men or animals
>
> d :  the therapeutic application of a pack
>
> e :  an act or instance of assembling in a compact group or mass
>
> 2
>   a :  a covering, stuffing, or holding apparatus used to protect, cushion, or brace goods packed for shipment or storage
>
> b (1) :  a thin layer or ring of elastic material (as paper, rubber, asbestos, copper) inserted between the surfaces of a flange joint to make it impervious to leakage — compare gasket (2) :  the material in a stuffing box which prevents leakage (3) :  a flexible ring surrounding a piston to maintain a tight fit (as inside a cylinder) (4) :  material (as felt, wool, or rope) placed in the sawway of a circular saw to prevent vibration — compare hydraulic packing, steam packing (5) :  caulking]
>
> c :  a masonry filling (as mortar containing small stones)
>
> d :  the material used beneath the drawsheet of a printing press
>
> e (1) :  longitudinal timbers between the hull of a ship and the sliding ways of a launching cradle (2) :  a liner between the frame and a raised strake of plating on a ship to make it watertight
>
> f :  the arrangement of several structural members (as I bars or struts) on a single pin forming a truss joint
>
> g :  the filling of a fractionating column consisting usually of loose pieces of solid material (as glass beads or Raschig rings)

None of these seem to apply. Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/send%20packing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the whole expression: **sent packing**. To be sent packing is an informal expression meaning to be sent away in disgrace, dismissed, removed from office, etc. When you leave a place where you have been living or staying, you first pack your possessions into one or more cases, bags, or boxes. One way of telling someone to leave is to say 'Pack your bags!'.

> send somebody packing
>
> informal
>
> to ask someone to leave immediately:
>   There were some kids at the door asking for money but I sent them packing.

[Send packing (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/send-sb-packing)